# Stop setInterval immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, velocity

**[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/28AC4/)**

I'm trying to make the background and text flash black and white, then stop when you click pause, but I notice there is a significant delay when you press the Pause button and the delay increases the longer you let the animation play.

I'm using Velocity.js, a jquery add-on, to do the animations.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var $title = $("#title");
  var $body = $("body");

  function blackout() {
    $title.velocity({
        colorRed: '+=100%',
        colorBlue: '+=100%',
        colorGreen: '+=100%'}, {loop: 1, duration: 50});
    $body.velocity({
        backgroundColorRed: '-=100%',
        backgroundColorBlue: '-=100%',
        backgroundColorGreen: '-=100%'
        }, {loop: 1, duration: 50})
    };

  $("#play").click(function() {
  var blackoutloop = setInterval(blackout, 100);
    $("#pause").click(function() {
        clearInterval(blackoutloop);
    });
  });

});
```

What is causing that delay and how do I fix it?

Comment: your `#pause` element click event should be set ouside the `#play` element click event otherwise you will be creating an additional click event for `#pause` each time you click `#play`

Comment: Epilepsy warning (rapid flashes in the jsfiddle)

Comment: no delay for me in chrome

Comment: no delay here either, works as advertised in Opera

Comment: The most likely reason is that the animations take slightly longer than 50ms, accounting the timer resolution and time to execute the code, and the animations are put into queue. If you change the interval to for example 120ms there's no delay.

Comment: Weird things happen if you click play more than once (it won't pause until you hit pause a few times).  You should probably check if it's playing and not assign another interval if it is.

Comment: use a recursive function with setTimout instead. Then you won't have overlaps

Comment: @charlietfl the `.velocity()` calls use their own internal timing mechanism so that won't really help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code implicitly assumes that the timing will work out perfectly, but in reality it won't. The Velocity.js code will consume some time doing DOM manipulation while implementing the animations, so every 100 milliseconds you're starting some animation that's a little bit delayed. The longer you allow the page to incapacitate all the epileptics in your vicinity, the longer that delay will be.

If you bump up the timer for the function to about 150 milliseconds, then (in my environment at least) it stops basically immediately on hitting "pause".  However note that I fixed a mistake in your code. Don't set up the "pause" handler in the "play" handler. Instead, do this:

```
  var blackoutloop;
  $("#play").click(function() {
    blackoutloop = setInterval(blackout, 150);
  });

  $("#pause").click(function() {
        clearInterval(blackoutloop);
  });
```

Also, in a jsfiddle:

- Don't include a `<body>` tag in the HTML part - the site does that for you
- If you're using the "On load" option for your code (as your fiddle does), there's no nead to wrap the code in a `$(document).ready()` call, as the site will put it in a "load" event handler on the `window`.